# Reading a large amount of numbers in python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a large amount of numbers (8112 in total) and rearrange them into 6 columns. First, I want to add 52 numbers to the first column, then I want to add 52 to the second, then 52 to the third, and so on. When I have the resultant 6 columns, each containing 52 numbers, I want to continue to reading in the same way till the end of data. I have try this:

```
with open('file.dat') as f:
    line = f.read().split()    
    for row in range(len(line)):
        for col in range(6):
            print line[row + 52*col],   
        print
```

The code is not reading correctly the numbers and does not got till the end. It is stooping after reading about 7000 numbers. I get an `Index error: list index out of range`.

The input file contains the numbers listed like this:

`-0.001491728991 -0.001392067804 -0.001383514062 -0.000777354202 -0.000176516325 -0.00066003232 0.001491728657 0.001392067465 0.00138351373 0.00077735388 0.000176516029 0.000660032023 -0.001491728966 -0.001392067669 -0.001383513988 -0.000777354111 -0.000176516303 2.5350931e-05 -0.000660032277 0.001491728631 0.00139206733 0.001383513657 0.000777353789 0.000176516006 0.000660031981 -0.003692742099 -0.003274685372 -0.001504168916 0.003692740966 0.003274684254 0.001504167874 -0.003692741847 -0.003274685132 -0.001504168791 (...)`

(8112 numbers in total)

Comment: One thing: shouldn't you be dividing the length by 6 to get the number of rows?

Comment: The problems is, I just saw now, that after it prints 52 numbers in the first column then the next in the secound but also after printing 6 columns of 52 numbers it starts to print again what is in the secound column...

Comment: How do you want the numbers in each column to appear next to one another, vertically or horizontally?

Comment: The first 52 numbers should go vertically then the next 52 numbers near printed as well vertically till 6 columns are complete, then start again. I edited an example above in the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: If  `row` is 7852 and `col` is 5 then you get `list index out of range` because `line[8112]` (7852+5*52 = 8112) does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data = range(8112) # replace with input from file

col_size = 52
col_count = 6
batch_size = (col_size*col_count)
# split input into batches of 6 columns of 52 entries each
for batch in range(0,len(data),batch_size):
    # rearrange line data into 6 column format
    cols = zip(*[data[x:x+col_size] for x in range(batch,batch+batch_size,col_size)])
    for c in cols:
        print c
```

output:

```
(0, 52, 104, 156, 208, 260)
(1, 53, 105, 157, 209, 261)
...
(50, 102, 154, 206, 258, 310)
(51, 103, 155, 207, 259, 311)
(312, 364, 416, 468, 520, 572)
(313, 365, 417, 469, 521, 573)
...
(362, 414, 466, 518, 570, 622)
(363, 415, 467, 519, 571, 623)
(624, 676, 728, 780, 832, 884)
(625, 677, 729, 781, 833, 885)
...
```